# How to fix "Too many arguments"-error

Tags: vb.net

im working on this point of sale system in vb and im stuck on an error

> Error 2   Too many arguments to 'Public Overridable Overloads Function
>   Insert(ItemName As String, BuyPrice As Integer?, SellPrice As
>   Integer?) As Integer'.

how can i clear it?

the double stared `**` is where the error is

my code: add item window

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

   Public Class AddItem

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
End Sub

'used to insert the item

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'perform validation for barcode
    If TextBox1.Text.Trim = "" Then
        MsgBox("You should enter a barcode number", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        TextBox1.Focus()
        Exit Sub

    End If

    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MsgBox("You should enter a numeric barcode number", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        TextBox1.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If TextBox1.Text.Contains(".") Or TextBox1.Text.Contains("-") Then
        MsgBox("The barcode number should not contain special characters", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        TextBox1.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'perform check for the item name
    If TextBox2.Text.Trim = "" Then
        MsgBox("You should enter a name for the item", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        TextBox2.Focus()
        Exit Sub

    End If

    'perform a check for the buy price
    If TextBox3.Text.Trim = "" Then
        MsgBox("You should enter the buying price", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        TextBox3.Focus()
        Exit Sub

    End If

    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox3.Text) Then
        MsgBox("You should enter a numeric buying price", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        TextBox3.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim BuyPrice As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
    If BuyPrice < 0 Then
        MsgBox("The buying price cannot be negative", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        TextBox3.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'perform a check for the selling price
    If TextBox4.Text.Trim = "" Then
        MsgBox("You should enter the selling price", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        TextBox4.Focus()
        Exit Sub

    End If

    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox4.Text) Then
        MsgBox("You should enter a numeric selling price", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        TextBox4.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim SellPrice As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(TextBox4.Text)
    If SellPrice < 0 Then
        MsgBox("The selling price cannot be negative", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        TextBox4.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If SellPrice <= BuyPrice Then
        MsgBox("The selling price cannot be less than buying price", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        TextBox4.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'perform check for quantity
    'If Not IsNumeric(TextBox5.Text) Then
    'MsgBox("You should enter a numeric digits", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    'TextBox5.Focus()
    'Exit Sub
    'End If

    'Dim Quantity As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(TextBox5.Text)
    'If Quantity < 0 Then
    'MsgBox("Quantity cant be negative", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    ' TextBox5.Focus()
    'Exit Sub
    'End If


    'insert the item

    Try
        'create the adapter
        Dim TA As New POSDSTableAdapters.ItemsTableAdapter

        'insert the item
        'TA.Insert(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, BuyPrice, SellPrice, Quantity)
        TA.Insert(TextBox2.Text, BuyPrice, SellPrice)


        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK

    Catch ex As Exception

        'display error message
        'handle error
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub AddItem_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

End Class

main window code:
Public Class MainWindow

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MyDataset.Items' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.ItemsTA.Fill(Me.MyDataset.Items)

    Try


    'get the username from the user
        'Dim USRWin As New PasswordPicker

    'get the password from the user
        ' Dim PSWWin As New PasswordPicker


    'if the user hits the exit button then stop executing the program
        'If PSWWin.ShowDialog <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        'End

        ' End If

        'get the usernme
        'Dim USR As String = USRWin.TextBox1.text
        'get the password
        'Dim PSW As String = PSWWin.TextBox2.text


        'get the password from the database
        ' Dim TA As New POSDSTableAdapters.ValuesTableAdapter
        'Dim TB = TA.GetDataByKey("password")
        ' Dim DBPSW As String = TB.Rows(0).Item(1)

        'check the passwords match
        ' If PSW <> DBPSW Then
        'MsgBox("Invalid password", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        ' End If

        'get the username
        ' Dim TK = TA.GetDataByKey("username")
        'Dim DBUSR As String = TK.Rows(0).Item(2)

        'check the username match
        'If USR <> DBUSR Then
        'MsgBox("Invalid username", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        'End If

        'load the items info from db into the dataset
        ItemsTA.Fill(MyDataset.Items)


    Catch ex As Exception

        'handle error
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)

End Sub

'add item to the db
Private Sub AddItemToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddItemToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim AddItemWindow As New AddItem
    If AddItemWindow.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        'load the info of items from db
        ItemsTA.Fill(MyDataset.Items)
    End If


End Sub

'used to select an item
Private Sub EditItemToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EditItemToolStripMenuItem.Click

    'make sure an item is selected
    If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'get the barcode of the item
    Dim Barcode = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value

    'create the edit window
    Dim EditItemWindow As New EditItem

    'fill the window with information
    EditItemWindow.FillItemInfo(Barcode)

    If EditItemWindow.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        'load the info of items from db
        ItemsTA.Fill(MyDataset.Items)
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't the error-message  self-explanatory?

> Too many arguments to 'Public Overridable Overloads Function
>   Insert(ItemName As String, BuyPrice As Integer?, SellPrice As
>   Integer?) As Integer'

You are passing four arguments at:

```
 TA.Insert(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, BuyPrice, SellPrice)
```

Maybe you want:

```
TA.Insert(TextBox1.Text, BuyPrice, SellPrice)
```

Comment: this codes works on other forms but on this one it doesnt and i need all four arguments to be inserted in the database

Comment: @user3454560: show all overloads of `Insert`. Is there one with four parameters?

Comment: @user3454560: the commented out statement above the one getting the error has five arguments to the Insert method. Is it possible that you are actually missing an argument?

Comment: the commented one it was also bringing an error so i reduced quantity and they remained four and it is still bringing an error @blackwood

Comment: their is no one with four parameters, their was one with five but i reduced it to 4 and still the error appears

Comment: @user3454560: As Tim asked, post all the forms of the Insert methed. The error message is clearly saying there isn't one that expects three arguments but you seem to think there is.

Comment: i already did.. to set of codes my additem.vb codes and mainwindow.vb codes

Comment: @user3454560: how is that code related to the compiler errors that you are trying to use `Insert` with four parameters? Show the (autogenerated) code of the table-adapter with the `Insert`-method.